# Hook for Template.rendered except in this case, I want it to be called for every rendered event

Tags: meteor

How can I call a function, or run some code for when any and every Template.rendered event is called in Meteor? (Not just a specific template)

(Is there a way I can do this without overloading meteor's base functions?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to call another method:

```
dothis = function() {
    // Something
}

Template.hello.rendered = function() {
   dothis();
}

Template.hello2.rendered = function() {
   dothis();
}
```

If you have nothing else to do in your rendered you could:

```
Template.hello2.rendered = dothis;
```

Also in bulk (will override any other rendered if it is defined before, when it is run):

```
for(tmpl in Template) {
    Template[tmpl].rendered = dothis;
};
```

(and also if you have defined stuff before you can make it run both callbacks:)

```
for(tmpl in Template) {
    if(Template[tmpl].rendered) {
        Template[tmpl].rendered = function() {
            var originalfunction = Template[tmpl].rendered;
            var result = originalfunction.apply(this);
            dothis.apply(this);
            return result;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Template[tmpl].rendered = dothis;
    }
};
```

Comment: ahh... a "decorator". i think i can just use http://underscorejs.org/#wrap for this case. thanks ;)

Comment: I never knew about `wrap` on underscore, Thank you!